# ESLint is not working?

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I Wanted to use ESLint to make my code better. 
I have installed it using the comand :

```
$ npm install -g eslint
```

later I ran the following command to generate a config file .
A file '.eslintrc.json' is created in my project's root directory

```
$ eslint --init
```

later i ran the following command :

```
$ eslint yourfile.js
```

but it didn't output any result.

later I have installed airbnb .

```
npm info "eslint-config-airbnb@latest" peerDependencies
```

also executed :

```
(
  export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
  npm info "$PKG@latest" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG@latest"
)
```

this created a folder 'eslint-config-airbnb' in /usr/lib/node_modules .

in '.eslintrc.json' file I placed "extends": "airbnb" .

then ran the command 'eslint filename.js'. It still doesn't output anything.Where did I go wrong ? Why am I unable to get the result ?

output screen shot : [eslint output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Xng.png)

config file screen shot :[.eslintrc.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ih3t.png)

Comment: Instead of screenshots, it would be a lot better if you can post the file contents here. People who want to help can simply copy and test it out for errors.

Comment: Thank you for being quick at response . My file has a lot of dependencies and can't post the content . Any working example of Eslint from your side or anyone else can help me out .

Comment: Looks like you are following the guidelines in https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started . Your elistrc file has a // in the 6th line. Remove that and try if it works.

Comment: yeah ! tried it too didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my advice:
Install ESLint locally, otherwise you need to ensure all ESLint dependencies, are globally installed.

Type this on your command line:

```
c:/somewhere> eslint
```

Now, there are two options:

1) **The ESLint Manual is shown:** ESLint is well configured and your cmd instance is located on the right path.

2) **Nothing happens**: Change your directory to node-modules/.bin and repeat.

```
c:/somewhere> cd c:/yourpersonalpath/node-modules/.bin
```

Once you solve the previous bullet point, start cmd in whatever folder you've installed ESLint (tipically node-modules/.bin) and type as follows:

```
c:/yourpersonalpath/node-modules/.bin> eslint absolutepathtojsfile.js
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

STEP 1

Project Directory: `node node_modules\eslint\bin\eslint.js --init`

---

STEP 2

I added the following scripts in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "set DEBUG=* & node app.js",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint app.js"
 }
```

Run the command `npm run lint` in terminal and it should start working.